# creating squares and rectangles in wxwidgets

Tags: drawing, wxwidgets, codeblocks, shapes

I'm working on an application, and part of it is making the user create a shapes such as squares or rectangles. I'm wondering if there is a function in wxwidgets that enable the user to do that. What i want to do is the user will click this button then he/she can draw a square or rectangle in his/her desired size. It is like in paint where you can make your own size in your desired size. Is that possible in wxwidgets and codeblocks? maybe some related links or tutorials or anything that will help. thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You should use this contrib library:

> Object Graphics Library
>
> OGL defines an API for applications that need to display objects connected by lines. The objects can be moved around and interacted with. You can find this in contrib/src/ogl, contrib/include/wx/ogl, and contrib/samples/ogl.

This is the link:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_utilities.html

Max

Answer (score 0):

Titles sais context here is "drawing", ok.

But in case you are talking about user-created rectangles as means of selecting stuff (or users end up here while searching for that context), jargon for that is rectangles as selection is "marquee selection", and you would look into Wx::Overlay to accomplish that.